# SSRS expression not working for Runningvalue

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

Please kindly suggest why my below expression not working

```
RunningValue(Fields!EXST_CHECK.Value,CountDistinct,"PROGRAM_DATA")/RunningValue(Fields!PATIENT_REGISTRATION_ID.Value,CountDistinct,"PROGRAM_DATA")
```

> Error - The Value expression for the text box ‘Textbox37’ has a scope
>   parameter that is not valid for RunningValue, RowNumber or Previous. 
>   The scope parameter must be set to a string constant that is equal to
>   the name of a containing group within the Tablix ‘Tablix4’.

Comment: Scope names are case sensitive so it must match the name of the row group exactly. If this does not help, edit your question to show the context of the expression. Is it in a tablix etc? screenshot of the design including group names would also be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Tested, and this one works for me (it also worked when I changed the Fields!SalesAmount.Value to a text field):

```
=RunningValue(Fields!SalesAmount.Value, CountDistinct, "DataSet1") / RunningValue(Fields!SalesAmount.Value, CountDistinct, "DataSet1")
```

This leaves just the option that you missspelled the name of the field or the name of the scope.